# What do you call the first string of characters inside an HTML tag?

Tags: html, terminology

This is an element: `<p class="blah">Hi World!</p>`

This is a tag: `<p class="blah">`

But what is the proper technical name for the `p` inside the tag?

Comment: `paragraph`, most probably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the [tag name](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-name). From [8.1.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags):

> 2. The next few characters of a start tag must be the element's tag name.

Answer (score -1):

It would be the `innerText` for that `p` element?